# Ubuntu doesnt showing left panel and action buttons on top of the windows

Tags: unity, compiz

I can open only some folders which are on desktop, but anyway they are without action buttons. When I try to run some programms like "google chrome", or "ccsm" via terminal (ctrl+alt+f1), i got error: `GtkWarning: could not open display.` Trying to run command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure compiz` , got answer:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [gnome_session]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 7: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general_ubuntu]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
```

Guest session and other user session are working, but main (mine) is not. What can i do ?

Comment: I doubt it'll help but you can try `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz`, followed by `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Nope, doesnt change anything ((

Comment: The dpkg-reconfigure failure is irrelevant here, just  chmod -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config

Answer (score 0):

To open an application from tty1 (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) in your xsession (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>), you must first export the display variable which specifies the xsession. Here's an example. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and sign in with your username and password. Then, run the following command:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Now you may execute the command to run the application and it should open in your xsession:

```
ccsm
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the xsession.

Now, scroll down to the unity plugin and enable it.

Please post any errors, don't worry about warnings.

Comment: Yes. i opened ccsm and turned on plugins, i checked all checkboxes which has guest session in ccsm window, but anyway the same problem.. I rebooted too, but nothing (

Comment: How does this answer the question? (not sarcastic, wondering)

Comment: @Zacharee1 what question, actually there is no question. I decided to tackle the almost error message (gtk warning) to show OP how to run a command on tty1 and have it start in the xsession '*When I try to run some programms like "google chrome", or "ccsm" via terminal (ctrl+alt+f1), i got error: GtkWarning: could not open display.*' Aside from that, it looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: @АрмандГрундманис Okay, if the "unity" plugin is enabled, you must disable the "window decoration" plugin  as they conflict.

Comment: @mchid "Window decoration" plugin is disabled (

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried many of resolutions in that link, nothing helps..

Answer (score 0):

Found resolution from other question answer:

> After many spent days and many SO threads read, I found that this
>   seems to be an Ubuntu open Bug (Status 'Incomplete' as of Juli 2015).
>   More information about it here: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1285444
>   The quick solution seems to be: $ mv ~/.config/dconf/user
>   ~/.config/dconf/user.old –  julianromera Jul 8 at 19:04

For me, answer is:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old
```

But default icons are displayed in left panel, not mine i was sorted earlier.

Comment: Well of course the launcher is reset. You essentially deleted the config. Glad you found a fix though.